# Desabilitar via CSS o submit do input quando div pai estiver 'display: none'

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu tenho duas `div`'s e fora delas um `input[type="radio"]`. Criei um CSS aonde, dependendo de qual radio está *checked*, uma div fica `display: block` e a outra permanece `display: none`. Dentro de cada uma dessas `div`'s têm vários outros `input`'s.

Eu gostaria que houvesse uma forma via CSS onde, caso a `div` esteja `display: none` seus `input`'s não sejam considerados na hora do submit do `form`.

Eu consigo fazer o tratamento pelo JavaScript, mas gostaria de fazer isso por CSS puro. É possível?

Meu HTML:

```
<div>
    <label for="aluno">Aluno</label>
    <input type="radio" name="cadastro" id="aluno">
    <label for="professor-cadastro">Professor</label>
    <input type="radio" name="cadastro" id="professor">
</div>

<!-- ALUNO -->
<div id="inputs-aluno" class="d-none inputs-aluno">
    <div>
        <label for="curso-cadastro">Curso:</label>
        <input type="text" name="curso-cadastro" id="curso-cadastro">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="matricula-aluno-cadastro">Matrícula:</label>
        <input type="text" name="matricula-aluno-cadastro" id="matricula-aluno-cadastro">
    </div>
</div>
<!-- ALUNO -->

<!-- PROFESSOR -->
<div id="inputs-professor" class="d-none inputs-professor">
    <div>
        <label for="area-cadastro">Área:</label>
        <input type="text" name="area-cadastro" id="area-cadastro">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="matricula-professor-cadastro">Matrícula:</label>
        <input type="text" name="matricula-professor-cadastro" id="matricula-professor-cadastro">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="lattes-cadastro">Lattes:</label>
        <input type="text" name="lattes-cadastro" id="lattes-cadastro">
    </div>
</div>
<!-- PROFESSOR -->
```

Meu CSS:

```
.d-none {
    display: none !important;
}

div:has(#aluno:checked) ~ .inputs-aluno,
div:has(#professor:checked) ~ .inputs-professor {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Enfim eu queria que os `input`'s ficassem com a mesma função caso tivessem o atributo `disabled`. Eu já tentei usar o `pointer-events: none`, conforme sugerido [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/466777/286443), porém o `pointer-events: none` apenas desabilita o `input` de ser editado pelo usuário, mas ele ainda é considerado no momento do submit (ou seja, funciona mais como um `readonly` do que como um `disabled`). Eu gostaria do `disabled`.

Comment: Se você gostaria que os inputs do tipo "text" não sejam considerados na hora do submit do form, talvez seja melhor (e mais seguro) realizar essa verificação do lado do servidor.

Comment: @Boneman foi o q imaginei, porém estou tentando praticar CSS e tentando forçar direto no CSS fazer coisas q antes eu só conseguia fazer com JavaScript. Se não houver como, eu farei do lado do servidor mesmo (apesar q nesse caso farei do lado do cliente pois isso é um exercício da faculdade onde só estamos usando HTML, CSS e JavaScript). Mas obrigado.

Comment: 1) Não tem como fazer somente com CSS. 2) Mesmo que os campos estejam invisíveis, eles serão enviados para o servidor, pois a única função do CSS é estilizar a página.

Comment: Ok obrigado @ValdeirPsr.